# How to use JQuery 'on()' with class selector filter?

Tags: jquery

Trying to update some old code from  `live()` to use `on()` and something is failing miserably.

```
$('#accordion').on('click','.EditModeDetails', function(event){
    alert('yay');
});
```

where `.EditModeDetails` is a class on injected HTML like so:

```
<li class="instructionText">
    <input value="EditModeDetails" class="EditModeDetails" name="EditModeDetails" type="checkbox">
    <label for="EditModeDetails">Edited text replaces existing text.  To add new text, check this box </label>
</li>
```

...and `#accordion` is an accordion control that is loaded at page load.

If I remove the filter, thus:

```
$('#accordion').on('click', function(event){
    alert('yay');
});
```

....I get alerts all over the place.

Have looked all over for a sample that uses a class instead of an element selector and having no luck.

EDIT:  Many thanks for the suggestions, guys, but nothing is working thus far  The version of JQuery that is loaded is ver--1.7.1.  Here is the link to the actual development:

http://esc.toypizza.com/sysalert

To see the problem, in the datatable click on http://esc.toypizza.com/_img/details_open.png followed by clicking on the http://esc.toypizza.com/_img/up_arrow.png that appears.  Next, click on the accordion section "Details" (above the "Current Issues" section that opens as the default).  You will see the offending checkbox to the right of the "Clear" button.

Comment: try this - $('.EditModeDetails').click(function(){alert('hello')});

Comment: @ChrisBrickhouse he said he is injecting the HTML

Comment: he can apply that event handler after injecting the html. if he is going to change the html or inject more, add .unbind() before the .click

Comment: It would be helpful to see the HTML markup all-the-way up to the `#accordion` element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/vczLh/ works just fine.

Comment: @mblase75 wrong example. you code does not contain future dom elements.

Comment: @RoyiNamir It's the best example I could come up with based on what I was given. I have no idea how he's adding to the DOM until he tells us.

Comment: Here is mblase75's jsfiddle with the ability to add DOM elements after load: http://jsfiddle.net/vczLh/1/

Comment: @RoyiNamir What for? I'm not the one who needs help with this. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an open div that is messing everything up.

```
<!--Accordian-->

<div id="accordion" class="invis">

    <h3><a href="#">Categories</a></h3>

<div><!--Accordian- panel OPEN-->
```

The `div#accordion` is closed several lines below, but the div that has the comment, `Accordian- panel OPEN` is not closed. This is causing the accordion to be misrendered and some elements are on top of the checkbox, that's why the event doesn't get to the check box.

Comment: Hmmmm...I don't think that that is the issue, either.  First, I used cold folding to check that my divs were closed and then when I could not find the un-closed tag that you were finding, I ran the page through HTMLTidy.  The result is at the page location, with the same result.

Comment: You are right, the divs are closed. But I insist that the problem is about some elements over the checkbox because of something not closed properly. I have created another answer with some things you should check. goold Luck!

Comment: I never figured out where the unclosed tag was, but I did figure out how to force everything to behave as-if everything was closed.  I dropped in a <span></span> before the tab control.

Answer (score 1):

### edit

Ive made a sample with future dom elements and its working

http://jsfiddle.net/vczLh/2/

there must be something else with your code.

1) are you sure you use 1.7 + ?

1.5)try to do : (for testing)

```
$('#accordion').on('click','.instructionText', function(event){
    alert('yay');
});
```

1.7) close the checkbox element with `/>`

and tell me if its fine ( we'll continue from there)

2) please upload more code

3) improve your accept rate.

4) your code is fine ( from what i see)

Comment: Roy--your fiddle appears to be precisely what I am doing, but for some reason mine is not working.  I have provided a link in my edited question to a live sample at http://esc.toypizza.com/sysalert

Answer (score 1):

stop the event from bubbling up and invoking click on all `li`s on the way up to `#accordion`

here is the [**problem**](http://jsfiddle.net/L5ddr/5/) you are having and here is the [**fix**](http://jsfiddle.net/L5ddr/6/)

```
$('#accordion').on('click','.EditModeDetails', function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
    alert('yay');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some elements are over the checkbox that's wey your are not getting the event triggered

May be you should check some other html

- You are using quoteless attribute definitions in some elements, I understand this is ok if you are declaring HTML5 doctype  `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- There is a link that is not closed `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/_css//escalate.css">`